# Jquery - Toggle, Show - need to wait before next effect

Tags: php, jquery

I use 4 link (submenu button) on my site. Every link open a DIV tag.

This DIV tags default stat is hide. (with jquery)

```
 $('div[class*="my_"]').hide();
```

After i click a submenu then i show() the div tag i need:

```
$('a#submenu_1').click( function() {

        $('div[class*="my_"]').hide(); // hide all DIV if some of them opened before
        $('div.my_submenu_1').toggle('slow'); 
  });
```

This is work well, till i patient to wait to hide if other DIV is opened before. But if im a click too fast between sub-menus then sometimes jquery can't HIDE the div tag before SHOWn the new.

My i use some dealy .. wait?

Could you suggest me something?!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Ghommey, but you may also want to do the show as part of the callback to hide() so that you know that all of the others are hidden first.

```
 $('div[class^="my_"]').stop().hide(0,function() {
      $('div.my_submenu_1').show('slow');
 });
```

Note, that you could probably rewrite this a little more generically.

```
 $('a.menu').click( function() {
      var menuID = $(this).attr('href');
      $('div.menu').stop().hide(0,function() {
          $(menuID).show('slow');
      });
      return false;
 });
```

where your HTML looks like:

```
 <a href="#my_menu_1" class="menu">Menu 1</a>
 <a href="#my_menu_2" class="menu">Menu 2</a>
 ...

 <div id="my_menu_1" class="menu">...</div>
 <div id="my_menu_2" class="menu">...</div>
```

This would have the advantage of having the link actually work if javascript were turned off.

Comment: That would cause problems if you click very fast wouldn't it?
Furthermore `.stop().hide();` is instant

Comment: I am using stop().hide() -- it's just that I've put the show into the callback so that it won't run unless the animation (hide) completes.

Comment: ...unless you mean the "normal" speed.  I've changed that to use a numeric value (0) -- which should be as fast as possible.

Comment: something wrong with this. fast switching between links, the show function frozen, and only part of the div shown...